# Signature digital algorithm in bitcoin, to what will it change in the future?

Tags: hash, signature, quantum-computing, signature-operations

in follow-up to the question: 85202
There, @Ugam Kamat wrote *""ECDSA is the first thing that can get vulnerable with quantum computer. signature will need to move to **post quantum world** much before quantum PoW.""*

My follow-up to that: 
to which signature concept are experts thinking on moving to in the future, any ideas circulating right now?

thx

Answer (score 1):

There's no consensus about the best post-quantum crypto encryption/authentication algorithms, but NIST has [a competition](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography) to choose the best post-quantum crypto algorithms that are asymmetric (where public key and private key different). Surely there's enough time to wait for the competition to end before spending any effort on post-quantum cryptocurrency (Exceptions: qBitcoin, which is impractical, and Bitcoin Candy, which has no progress)